# Postgresql query with where, order by and limit very slow

Tags: postgresql

I have trouble with my table, it has 30-40m records when I execute query:

```sql
select * 
      from table c 
   where c.column_a in (111111, 22222222, 333333333) 
   order by c.column_b 
   limit 30
```

it's very slow. But when I remove order by clause, the query executes very fast.
I have 2 indexes: idx_column_a and multi-column index idx_column_a_column_b
what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Try `create index idx_column_b on table (column_b)` and run the query again. If that doesn't help `drop index idx_column_b` and try multi-column index `create index idx_column_b_a on table (column_b, column_a)` and see if that helps. I am curious if either of these help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll give it a try.

Comment: please share the result of EXPLAIN ANALYSE with your queries to better understand the reasons of the bad performances

Comment: I tried to execute this query, but it's too slow to finish :( the statement_timeout is 30 seconds.

Comment: Can't you change the statement_timeout?  Anyway, you can at least show a plain EXPLAIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get fast execution from your multi-column index by rewriting the query like this:

```
(select * from t c where c.column_a =1 order by c.column_b)
union all
(select * from t c where c.column_a =2 order by c.column_b)
union all
(select * from t c where c.column_a =3 order by c.column_b)
order by column_b limit 30;
```

It is a shame PostgreSQL won't generate this fast execution for you with the natural way of writing the query, maybe some day it will.  (I gave the table the legal name, and made your constants less repetitive.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I fixed it, but it's seem that my wrong postgresql configuration :( My Server has 64GB ram and 20 cores, and the postgresql.conf is : 
#max_connections = 200
#shared_buffers = 16GB
#effective_cache_size = 32GB
#maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
#checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
#wal_buffers = 16MB
#default_statistics_target = 100
#random_page_cost = 1.1
#effective_io_concurrency = 200
#work_mem = 20971kB
#min_wal_size = 1GB
#max_wal_size = 4GB
#max_worker_processes = 20
#max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 4
#max_parallel_workers = 20